# Ubuntu Studio for Ubuntu SDK

Tags: application-development, performance, ubuntu-sdk, ubuntu-studio

I have one of the strange question in my mind. I saw Ubuntu studio is good for multimedia related thing. I was wondering this thing for past few days.

Is it possible to Install Ubuntu SDK in Ubuntu Studio?

- If yes, how it will be helping with development. Will be performance
  will be good in Ubuntu studio compared to Normal Ubuntu.
- Can I develop apps in test them there. Will be similar as we develop in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu studio is nothing but Ubuntu with some special music/video related softwares. The customisability of Ubuntu(or GNU/Linux in general) that you can install any linux software on any linux distro (doesn't mean it will work).

So you can do everything that you do on Ubuntu, on Ubuntu studo as well.You can develop, test do everything.

Comment: Since it is more related to multimedia, will be testing performance with emulator will be good.

Comment: That doesn't matter. What matters is that you have enough RAM and processor required by the software you are using.

Comment: I have used Ubuntu SDK well in my Ubuntu machine which is having 4gb RAM and i3 processor. It is great. I thought since developing application uses lot of things like photo edition, designing UI and testing the apps it will be useful. But sometimes my Android emulator stops responding, i felt may be due to some problems. So during such times Ubuntu studio may help, since  it is built for running big process.

Comment: @VP7 Linux is so customizable that you can convert one distro to other.If you don't want to spend time tweaking things in Ubuntu which are ready-made in Ubuntu studio, you could use Studio.But the OS does not make significant difference as long as your computer is powerful enough(In your case, you have enough powerful computer)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Studio is two things:

- Custom Kernel allowing realtime processing (for better performance in
  encoding audio, exporting videos, etc)
- Custom Packages, which I found is particularly useful for setting up
  JACK (which is a headache otherwise).

You should be able to get the SDK (qtcreator) for it, although considering that it is generally encouraged to develop in ubuntu's upcoming version, you may want to consider going with 14.04 (or 14.10 in a few weeks). You can generally develop applications on any platform though, although this depends of course on the applications you are actually planning to program.